# How can I get rid of this error based on list index out of range in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping data from amazon website.The aim is to get the product title and the correspnding ASIN(Amazon Standard Identification Number).Can someone please suggest me how to solve this error.
Thanks in advance...!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as url_req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
my_lists = ['nike','addias']
for list in my_lists:
    url1= "https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="
    url2 = "&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A"
    driver.get(url1 + str(list) + url2)
    new_url = driver.current_url
    uclient= url_req(new_url)
    page_html = uclient.read()
    uclient.close()
#html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
try:
    title = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class": "s-result-item s-result-card-for-container a-declarative celwidget"})
    print(title[0].textstrong text)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exceptions_Found",format(e))

sleep(5)
print ("Query link: ",driver.current_url)
driver.back()
sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Try checking if `title[0]` exists before printing it using an `if` statement. Also you could try looping through title as `for item in title:`

Comment: Hi Chris Thanks for the answer.Since I am new to the programming.Can you please help me change the code and do the neccessary modifications.So that it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with your HTML parser part. Here is the solution.

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
try:
    import re
    results_list = page_soup.findAll("li", id=re.compile("^result"))
    #for getting title of all results
    for titles in results_list:
        print(titles.find('h2').text)
    #for getting title of only first result
    for title in results_list[0]:
        print(title.find('h2').text)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exceptions_Found",format(e))
```